# Printing only the text that appears between two symbols

Tags: macros, context

I have a macro which contains some text:

```
\textmacro{This is some text.}
```

Normally, when compiled, it should just print text, like this:

```
This is some text.
```

Sometimes, the text contains “①”and “②”, such as this:

```
\textmacro{①  This is some text. ② This is some other text.}
```

When that happens, I need it to only print the text appearing between “①”and “②”, like this:

```
This is some text.
```

How can I make the macro print the text between “①” and “②” in `#1`, if those symbols appear, otherwise, to just print all of the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a ConTeXt answer, right? Whenever I catch myself thinking "I know how to do this in an ordinary programming language", I shunt the text I want to operate on into LuaTeX. Taking [the template from the wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Programming_in_LuaTeX#Passing_arguments_and_buffers%3a_ConTeXt_commands_that_hook_into_Lua):

```
% First, the Lua function that will process the string
\startluacode
    -- remember, using the userdata namespace prevents conflicts
    userdata = userdata or {}

    function userdata.printBetweenMarks(str, m1, m2)
        -- default delimiters
        m1 = m1 or '①'
        m2 = m2 or '②'

        match_pattern = string.format('%s(.*)%s', m1, m2)
        str = string.match(str, match_pattern) or str
        context(str)
    end
\stopluacode

% Secondly, the ConTeXt command that passes the string to the Lua function.

\def\textmacro#1%
    {\ctxlua{userdata.printBetweenMarks([===[#1]===])}}
    % Note that Lua sees the text as-is, so we have to wrap it in string
    % delimiters ourselves.
    % [=*[ is Lua's double-bracket string delimiter style; this way, the
    % code only fails if the text contains ']===]'.
```

EDIT: removed a `print()` statement I had used for debugging

Comment: I was thinking of adding a `lpeg` based solution, but your solution is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks! Add your solution anyway, perhaps, if you feel like it? There's More Than One Way To Do It, after all; and `lpeg` scales in complexity better than `string.match`; and reading your answer will help me improve my woeful `lpeg` knowledge/understanding. ;-)

Comment: Can `userdata.printBetweenMarks([===[#1]===])}` be placed within another `\startlua` and `\stoplua`? I tried placing it there, but just get errors.

Comment: @Village: that gives errors because you can't use `#1` when you're not defining a TeX macro. (In my example, `\ctxlua` _was_ part of a macro definition.) Things that will work: `userdata.printBetweenMarks([=[① mystring ②]=])` (more on [strings in Lua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringsTutorial); and `userdata.printBetweenMarks(str)`, where `str` is a variable containing the string you want to work on. Read this [tutorial on LuaTeX](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Programming_in_LuaTeX#Passing_arguments_and_buffers:_ConTeXt_commands_that_hook_into_Lua) for more info.

Comment: Three snippets that may help you:
**(1)** `\ctxlua{str = "mystring"}` (or `'mystring'`, `[[mystring]]`, `[=[mystring]=]`, etc.); **(2)** `\def\savestring#1{\ctxlua{str = "#1"}}` followed by `\savestring{asdf}`; and **(3)** `\def\passStringToFunction{\ctxlua{myfunction("#1")}}`.

Answer (score 12):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\textmacro#1{\expandafter\@textmacro#1①②\@nil}
\def\@textmacro#1①#2②#3\@nil{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax#1\else#2\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\textmacro{This is some text.}\par
\textmacro{①  This is some text. ② This is some other text.}\par
\textmacro{This is some text ①  This is some other text. ② This is some text.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Notice that if one uses this with `pdflatex` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, the second example fails because of the `\expandafter`. +1 anyway. :)